# How can I run an Ansible block one host at a time?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook with something like this:

```yaml
- name: Do this all one host at a time
  block:
    - name: Task A
      # do task A
    
    - name: Task B
      # do task B
  throttle: 1
```

I expect `throttle: 1` to limit execution to one of the hosts at a time.  It does this, but instead of running the whole block on host 1, then the whole block on host 2, etc. it runs Task A on host 1, Task A on host 2, Task B on host 1, Task B on host 2.

How can I run the entire block on each host in the group, one at a time?

(Note: there are other tasks in the playbook that should not run serially, hence not having the entire playbook run this way.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that on a block. What you are looking for is [`serial`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#setting-the-batch-size-with-serial) on a play. In a nutshell:

```yaml
- name: Play those tasks serially
  hosts: my_group
  serial: 1

  tasks:
    - name: Task A
      # do task A
    
    - name: Task B
      # do task B
```

Comment: My issue with this is that only some of the tasks in the playbook should be run serially

Comment: @HorseHair, you may have a look into [Using keywords to control execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#using-keywords-to-control-execution), Quote: "_In addition to strategies, several keywords also affect play execution._", which indicates that you would need to structure your plays accordingly.

Comment: You can have multiple plays in a playbook, all targeting the same group(s)/host(s). e.g. play 1 all hosts, in parallel; play 2 all hosts, in series, play 2 all hosts, in parallel again.

Comment: yeah but my question is can you use serial in a block, for the whole block, instead of at the play level, so that i dont have to make another role for rolling upgrades (nomad), when i already have the nomad code in place that works well?

Comment: You can't do that since `serial` is a play level keyword. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html.